# Bash Regex to print out the matched string only?

Tags: regex, bash

Im trying to read a file line by line and trying to match few strings,and im not able to echo the matched line using "$?" im not sure which "$" function to use. can anyone help? i dont want using grep, thanks in advance.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
while read EachLine
    do
    if [[ "$EachLine =~ ^Pass: [0-9]\{1,\}" ]]
        then
    echo "$?"
    fi 
    done < zoix.progress-N0
exit
```

Comment: You're quotting your code wrongly. It should be : `if [[ "$EachLine" =~ "^Pass: [0-9]\{1,\}" ]]`. Also, `$?` returns the exit code, not the matched content

Comment: This looks like a job for grep.

Comment: @Bob Banner: Can you please show us content of sample input file and the strings you want to match, so that its more clearer.

Comment: Part: 0 Pass: 1 SimTime: 2556565     \n   Probe Time: 547676767 \n   Pass: 2

Comment: `\{1,\}` is a poor and slightly silly way of saying `+`

Comment: @Aserre Don't quote regular expressions, from `man bash`: *"Any part of the pattern may be quoted to force the quoted portion to be matched as a string."*.

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann yeah, my bad, I noticed that after the 5 minutes grace period for the edit. Also, the question I linked as dupe addresses this point exactly, so I should have been more careful :/

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies several problems with the code.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to put out the lines that match your pattern in a file, have you tried the following:

```
grep -E "^Pass: [0-9]+" zoix.progress-N0
```

Comment: thank you, but i don't wanna do it using grep command.

Comment: Not even if we persuade you that that is obviously the better approach for a number of reasons?